# Segmentation fault in the first line

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Today i was solving a problem and I coded the solution and I got segmentation fault in the very first line and i tried many things but nothing is working

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long int ll;
#define fastio ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);
#define INF 0x3f3f3f3f3f

ll dist(ll x1 , ll x2 , ll y1 , ll y2){

    ll x = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2);
    ll y = (y1-y2)*(y1-y2);

    return ( x+y );
}

int main() {

    fastio;

    ll n,m;
    ll a[1005][2];
    ll b[1005][2];
    ll dp[1005][1005][2];

    cin >> n >> m;
    for(ll i = 1; i <= n; i++) cin >> a[i][0] >> a[i][1];
    for(ll i = 1; i <= m; i++) cin >> b[i][0] >> b[i][1];



    for(ll i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (ll j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            dp[i][j][0] = INF;
            dp[i][j][1] = INF;
        }
    }

    dp[0][0][0] = 0;
    dp[0][0][1] = 0;
    dp[1][0][0] = 0;

    for(ll i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(ll j = 0; j <= m; j++){

            // dp[i][j][0] :
            if(i > 1) dp[i][j][0] = min(dp[i][j][0] , dp[i-1][j][0] + dist(a[i-1][0] , a[i][0] , a[i-1][1] , a[i][1]));
            if(i > 1 && j >= 1 ) dp[i][j][0] = min(dp[i][j][0] , dp[i-1][j][1] + dist(b[j-1][0] , a[i][0] , b[j-1][1] , a[i][1]));

            // dp[i][j][1] :

            if(j > 1 ) dp[i][j][1] = min(dp[i][j][1] , dp[i][j-1][0] + dist(a[j-1][0] , b[j][0] , a[j-1][1] , b[j][1]));
            if(j > 1 ) dp[i][j][1] = min(dp[i][j][1] , dp[i][j-1][1] + dist(b[j-1][0] , b[j][0] , b[j-1][1] , b[j][1]));

        }
    }

    cout << dp[n-1][m-1][0];

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/MzbX2HPQ

Pls let me know what should i change ??

Thanks 
Sudheera Y S

Comment: What does your stdin input looks like?

Comment: You are declaring arrays of huge sizes within `main` and thus probably blowing out the stack memory.  Use `std::vector` instead.  Also this shortcut "competitive programming" stuff is not looked upon very well among many here.  Things like those awful macros and `typedefs` and usage of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here (I will not use the `typedef`, but the actual type):

```
int main()
{
    long long a[1005][2];
    long long b[1005][2];
    long long dp[1005][1005][2];
    //...
}
```

Since these arrays are local to `main`, there needs to be enough stack memory to hold these arrays.  If we assume that `sizeof(long long)` is 8, then the total memory being used is over 16 megabytes.  The default stack size for most compilers is less than 8 megabytes.

Thus to prevent this, allocation from the heap should be done.  That can be accomplished using `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
using Array1D = std::vector<long long>;
using Array2D = std::vector<Array1D>;
using Array3D = std::vector<Array2D>;

int main()
{
    Array2D a(1005, Array1D(2)) ;
    Array2D b(1005, Array1D(2)) ;
    Array3D dp(1005, Array2D(1005, Array1D(2)));
    //...
}
```